# Perl Net::SFTP::Foreign Plink connection issue

Tags: windows, perl, ssh, sftp, plink

Firstly i'm a complete sftp & ssh newbie, and pretty new to Perl. I am trying to write a script to connect to a remote server and retrieve files. Both servers are windows 2003 boxes. i have installed an sftp server on the server and can connect using the filezilla client with the same ip adress (removed from code sample for security reasons), username, and port number specified in my code.

The connection block of code i have is:

```
my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new(
    host    => 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx', 
    user    => 'radiospx', 
    port    => '22', 
    ssh_cmd => "C:\\Program Files\\putty\\plink.exe",
    more    => [qw(-v -i )]
); 

$sftp->error and die " SSH connection failed: " . $sftp->error;
```

When i run the script i get the following output:

Looking up host "sftp"
unable to open connection: Host does not exist SSH connection failed: Connection to remote server is broken at import.pl line 34

Can anyone suggest where i'm going wrong. the server is definitely accepting sftp connections  as filezilla works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

the `-i` plink option you are passing through `more` requires an argument:

```
my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new(
    host    => 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx', 
    user    => 'radiospx', 
    port    => '22', 
    ssh_cmd => "C:\\Program Files\\putty\\plink.exe",
    more    => ['-v', -i => "C:\\path\\to\\the\\private.key"]
); 

$sftp->error and die " SSH connection failed: " . $sftp->error;
```

Comment: Thanks @salva, does sftp always require a key pair to be set up? 

If i remove the -i plink option i get the output:
    Looking up host "<<ip address>>"
    Connecting to <<ip address>> port 22
    Failed to connect to <<ip address>>: Network error: Connection refused
    Network error: Connection refused
    FATAL ERROR: Network error: Connection refused
    SSH connection failed: Connection to remote server is broken at
    import.pl line 34.

Comment: @user543464: try connecting with plink from the command line: `"C:\program files\putty\plink.exe" -P 22 radiospx@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx`, what do you get?